# Number of lines and columns of an array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created a program that worked well in DevC++ at the college but when back to home it didn't work in Code::Blocks and I don't know what's wrong. I want to count the numbers of lines and columns of a 2D array of integers (all 0), and then I found that the method I use is uncorrect even with 1D array. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define L 5
#define C 2
#define N 10

int main()
{
    int T[L][C],M[N],i=0,j=0,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<L;i++) for(j=0;j<C;j++) T[i][j]=0;
    for(k=0;k<N;k++) M[k]=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;
    while(T[i][0]==0) i++;
    while(T[0][j]==0) j++;
    while(M[k]==0) k++;
    printf("The number of lines is: %d.\nThe number of columns is: %d.\n",i,j);
    printf("The number of lines is: %d.\nThe number of columns is: %d.\n",L,C);
    printf("The number of lines is: %d.\n",k);
    printf("The number of lines is: %d",N);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C arrays do not carry the information of their own size. As well as pointers to not "know" to how much memory they point. In both case the porgrammer needs to take care to store this info somewhere somehow if it is needed at a later time.

Comment: the function 'getch()' is not part of the two header files you included.  The result is the code does not compile cleanly.  suggest using either: 1) getchar(); or 2) system( "pause" );

Comment: the 'while' loops will lead to undefined behaviour as they can/will access memory outside the bounds of the arrays.  This can/will lead to seg fault events

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
@alk For 1D arrays we can write sizeof(nameofthearray)/sizeof(typeofthearay) (in our case sizeof(M)/sizeof(int)).

Comment: @user3629249 Yes you're right! I checked the information and in fact we need to include conio. But in Code::Blocks and DevC++ it works which is weird. Anyway getchar(); doesn't work it doesn't make the program pause, and I usually don't like in my exercises the message that appears with system("Pause");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your conditions are wrong.

```
while(T[i][0]==0) i++;
while(T[0][j]==0) j++;
while(M[k]==0) k++;
```

there are chances that 0 is present even after the memory alloted. In your older versions where there is not index range checking or out of bound exception it can go on and on even after it has reached the specified length.
so your approach to find length of the array is wrong. Moreover if there is not dynamic allocation of memory for array, and you know your array is going to have fixed length, why bother checking it's size. From what I see, you want to count no. of certain values in your array, well then for it there are many algorithms present for searching. apply one of those :)

Comment: You're right! So it was just by luck that it worked correctly at College. Thank you for the advices!

Comment: yeppe :) Merry Christmas to me. hehehe and all :)

Answer (score 3):

In this statement,

```
while(T[i][0]==0) i++;
```

`i` value will keep on incrementing, but where is the bound check for `i`? It may very well go beyond the actual allocated dimension of the defined array and result in [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Same goes for `while(T[0][j]==0) j++;` and `while(M[k]==0) k++;` also.

Comment: @Scientifica you're welcome. BTW, what you consider as _luck_, I consider as _bad luck_, because, you'll end up having a wrong value with absolutely no idea that you're having a wrong value. A segmentation fault will save you most of the cases. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answze and yes it's bad luck. In fact my comment is to Codeek and wrongly posted it to you. Well the bound check for i is T[i][0]==0 it self, no?

Comment: @Scientifica mark my words, bound check for _array index_. Clear now? :-) Once you're `i` has reached, say `6`, then you're already facing undefined behaviour and you can't predict the value of `arr[6][0]`.

Comment: Well when i=0 the computer checks if T[0][0]==0 if so i++ and then i becomes 1 and the computer checks if T[1][0]==0 and so on.

Comment: @Scientifica yes, and that way it goes upto `4`, right? `T[4][0]` is `0`, so `while` success, `i++` done and now `i` is `5`. then , `T[5][0]`....bingo..undefined behaviour. :-)

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding you "Undefined behavior" is new to me, in fact I'm beginner in progamming so I didn't understand only through Wikipedia untill looking for it in Google. Thank you for your answers.
Men why can't I give more than 1 green for accepting answer?